How to effectively review chat bot changes in Github?
When the chatbot version is edited, each item in the chatbot version (dialog, variable etc) usually gets a new Id and this is displayed as modification to git version control system.
When the chatbot version is huge, this means we need to review 3,262 dummy changes in average which is insane since we can't distinguish identifier dummy changes from any real changes in the chatbot logic.
How can we effectively review chatbot changes so that we can easily review any real changes and ignore any dummy identifier changes?

